# IndexWriter deleteDocuments function is not working

Tags: apache, lucene

```
public void index(IndexItem indexItem) throws IOException {
    writer.deleteDocuments(new Term(IndexItem.ID,indexItem.getId().toString()));                    
    Document doc = new Document();
    // doc.add(new LongField(IndexItem.ID, indexItem.getId(), Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField(IndexItem.CONTENT, indexItem.getContent(), Field.Store.NO));
    doc.add(new StringField(IndexItem.PATH, indexItem.getPath(), Field.Store.YES));

    // add the document to the index
    writer.addDocument(doc, analyzer);


    writer.updateDocument(new Term(IndexItem.CONTENT, indexItem.getContent().toString()), doc);
    System.out.println(indexItem.getTitle()); 
    writer.close();
}
```

Here Writer.deleteDocuments is not working. Thus each time I index a file, it doest not deletes already existing file then create a new one rather it just makes a copy of it.

Is this anything have to do with work.lock file

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have commented out the line that adds the `IndexItem.ID` field to the document.  If that field isn't added to the document, then the call to `deleteDocuments` won't find any matches on that field, and nothing will be deleted.

Comment: Oh sorry that was my typing mistake, the error has been resolved. And thank you sir for your response.

Comment: @myk. how did you resolve it? I have a similar problem.